# better understand vs better understanding

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm looking for a category title. This category will list some articles about personal development. Which one would be the best option:

```
better understand personal development 
or
better understanding personal development
```

Notice that I want to avoid "understand personal development" since we can only "better understand" it (its a complex matter we can't yet fully understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two given, I would go with the first (*better understand personal development*). It is easily understood and a natural word order (you could stick "how to" in front of it and it would read perfectly well).

The second (*better understanding personal development*) has issues:

1. While correct, it wouldn't be *my* preferred word order, at least (I'd say "understanding personal development better").
2. It is too easily read as "better understanding **of** personal development", in which case the lack of "of" makes it look like a mistake.

That said, I would suggest simply *understanding personal development*. You're right, we can't *completely* understand it, but using the continual aspect ("understanding") takes care of that, in my mind.

And merely *personal development* might be even better, unless you want to have several categories about personal development, of which "understanding" is just one.